# How recursive function control flow change for static variable?

Tags: c++, recursion

I am trying to learn some stuff about recursive function and I try to run this

```
void recurse()
{
   static int c = 1;
   if(c > 5)
      return ;
   printf("%d ",c);
   c = c + 1;
   recurse();
   printf("%d ",c);
}

int main()
{
   recurse();
   return 0;
}
```

I am expecting that it will give me an output like this as similar to any local variable called in a recursive function.

```
1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 1
```

But compiler gives me an output like this

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 6 6 6 6
```

I can't understand why this kind of output comes. Can anyone explain?

Comment: It will be helpful for you to follow each line of code like a computer would for a lesser value of `c`, say 2 or 3.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The series of 6s is printed because of the second `printf` in `recurse()`.

By the time the recursive calls are complete the value of `c` has already been incremented upto 6. So it will print 6 five times.

If you want the output to be `1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 1`, use another variable `d` and increment/decrement it based on the value of `c` under appropriate conditions.

```
void recurse()
{
    static int c = 1; int d;

    if(c > 5) {
        d = d - 1;
         return ;
    }
    printf("Count = %d\n",c);
    d = c;
    c = c + 1;
    recurse();
    printf("Count = %d\n",d);
}
```

See demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0685e1780abdc5b0).

Comment: The second printf will execute only after all the returns of the calls to recurse. At that point of the time c has been incremented to 6.

Comment: @MuhammadArifulIslam: Updated the answer to give the output you were expecting.

Comment: But why output differs in this case: calling the `recurse(int c)` function from the main function as `recurse(1)`. It showing me output as `1 2 3 4 5 5 4 3 2 1`

Comment: Because you are incrementing `c` in the `recurse` function.

Comment: Can You refer me any documentation for better clarification of those things? Thanks for Your answer :)

Comment: @MuhammadArifulIslam: Only for recursion or C++ topics?

Comment: Only for recursion.